# Painful querying API with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm starting to learn firebase with firestore.

I have spent more hours than I would've like understanding the reference type and trying to get it to work with a simple query that references a portfolio's category.

This is the code:

```
try {
  const portfolioSnap = await db.collection("portfolio").get();
  let portfolioDoc = portfolioSnap.docs;
  let categoriesRef = [];
  portfolioDoc.forEach(p => {
    categoriesRef.push(p.data().category.get());
  });
  let categories = await Promise.all(categoriesRef);
  let portfolio = [];
  portfolioDoc.map((p, i) => {
    let portfolioObject = {
      ...p.data(),
      category: categories[i].data().name
    };
    portfolio.push(portfolioObject);
  });
  return portfolio;
} catch (error) {
  console.warn("ERROR: ", error);
}
```

I'm not sure if this makes sense.

I'm trying to get the `category` for each `portfolio` document but I feel this is over-engineered or I'm totally doing it the wrong way.

And this is not counting if I have references for images or files which I feel would make things... well, not pretty.

Comment: LGTM, so you have two separate collections for portfolios and categories. When fetching the list of portfolios you loop through this list and fetch the corresponding category. You can totally do it like that. You can optimize it by pulling all the categories and mapping them client side. It would reduce the request from n to 1 however the response size would be bigger.

Comment: What do you mean fetch them on the client side or how to reduce the request to 1, cause right now it has a request for each portfolios category.

Comment: A: you fetch all the categories, B: you fetch all the portfolios, C: you map categories to portfolios without have a category request per portfolio

Comment: how would you do C in this case? I have a reference to the category in each portfolio but in order to get the data I need to do a loop in all portfolio records to get that single category

Comment: C: you loop through the portfolios, per portfolio you loop through all categories, if you reach the matching category you break the inner loop.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing strange here.  This is the way that nosql databases work (since there is no join operation, nor is there any explicit relationships between documents other than what you define).

Comment: I had a feeling this would've been the answer.